# Visualg não reconhece o "fimse"

Tags: java, princípios-de-programação, recuperação-de-erros

Meu algoritmo é esse abaixo:

Questão.
Solicite o ano de casamento, o ano atual e escreva as seguintes mensagens, para os seguintes casos: 25 anos - "Bodas de Prata"; 50 anos - "Bodas de Ouro" e 75 anos - "Bodas de Diamante". Nos casos restantes escrever apenas o número de anos de casados.

Porém ele não reconhece o "fimse" sempre pondo aviso de erro:

```
Algoritmo:

Algoritmo "semnome"
// Disciplina   : [Linguagem e Lógica de Programação]
// Professor   : Antonio Carlos Nicolodi 
// Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
// Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
// Data atual  : 18/10/2020
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
casa,ano,t: real

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
escreval("Digite o ano do casamento:")
leia(casa)
escreval("Digite o ano atual")
leia(ano)
t<-casa-ano
        se t=25 entao
        escreval("Bodas de Prata")
        se t=50 entao
        escreval("Bodas de Ouro")
        se t=75 entao
        escreval("Bodas de Diamante")
        senao
        escreval("O resultado é:", t)
        fimse

Fimalgoritmo
```

[image: Tá ai uma print do erro]

Comment: As regras de sintaxe do VisuAlg exigem um `fimse` para cada `se`, no seu caso estão faltando e portanto seu programa está incompleto.

Comment: vlw! Ajudou bastante msm! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está abrindo vários(apenas 3, esqueceu de 2) `se` mas apenas fechou um, não é que ele não reconhece, apenas você que esqueceu de fechalos.

O código ficara assim:

```
Algoritmo:

Algoritmo "semnome"
// Disciplina   : [Linguagem e Lógica de Programação]
// Professor   : Antonio Carlos Nicolodi 
// Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
// Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
// Data atual  : 18/10/2020
Var
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
casa,ano,t: real

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
escreval("Digite o ano do casamento:")
leia(casa)
escreval("Digite o ano atual")
leia(ano)
t<-ano-casa
        se t=25 entao
        escreval("Bodas de Prata")
        fimse 
        se t=50 entao
        escreval("Bodas de Ouro")
        fimse
        se t=75 entao
        escreval("Bodas de Diamante")
        senao
        escreval("O resultado é:", t)
        fimse

Fimalgoritmo
```

Também troquei o `casa-ano` para `ano-casa` pois sempre daria resultado negativo.

Comment: Vlw pessoal! Sou iniciante em programação, então me desculpe pelos erros! Vlw msm! ja ia desistir

Comment: Que bom que você gostou da resposta! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Não desista!